# Alert box cuando imagen aparece?

Tags: javascript

No tengo buendo nivel de javascript por que acabo de empezar. Mi pregunta es: Como hago que aparezca el alert box en el momento que en la pagina aparece una imagen?

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías replantear la pregunta de otra manera? Resulta poco concreta y confusa.

Comment: Pues entoces vamos asi. Este juego esta en un browser, es un juego de pokemon donde estos pueden aparecer de 5 formas shiny,metal,void,albino,ghost. Cuando le doy a inspect element me aperece que shiny, metal etc son imagenes. Lo que yo quiero es que en el momento en el que la imagen void aparezca Por ejemplo: Pikachu (void), en ese mismo momento que salga el alert box. Podria anadir imagenes pero no se como

Comment: Necesitas estar pendiente de si se producen cambios en el DOM de la página. Para eso puedes usar la API MutationObserver que hace justamente eso. Es relativamente sencilla de usar:  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: en cuanto a tu puntualización de que acabas de empezar con JavaScript, te recomiendo realizar el tutorial de w3schools ya que me parece que es bastante completo y está muy bien explicado, a parte tiene muchos ejemplos interactivos y ejercicios: https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: Perdona xero399, pero no entiedo como usar el mutation observer

Comment: @YuSinn, por favor todas las aclaratorias y complementos a la pregunta hazlo en la misma pregunta y no en los comentarios. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para ello. También aprovecho para darte la bienvenida a [es.so] y te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: @xero399 si te doy la pagina web o a lo mejor mi discord te podria ensenar exactamente lo que quiero hacer

Comment: @YuSinn acabo de publicarte un ejemplo con comentarios de cómo usar el MutantObserver

Comment: @xero399 hola otra vez, no logro como hacer el problema, no se como introducir la imagen en el if

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Como decía en los comentarios de la pregunta, debes comprobar cuando se añade un elemento, por ejemplo con la API MutationObserver. Te dejo un ejemplo que he hecho para que veas cómo funciona.

```js
//Quiero observar los cambios en el elemento "contenido"
var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");

//Función para añadir elementos al contenido
document.getElementById("botonAnadir").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var nuevo = document.createElement("button");
  nuevo.setAttribute("type", "button");
  nuevo.innerHTML = "Eliminar";
  //Función para eliminar elementos del contenido
  nuevo.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.target.remove();
  });
  contenido.appendChild(nuevo);
});

//Creo el observer con una función callback que se ejecuta cada vez que se produce un cambio.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  //Para cada cambio ejecuto lo siguiente
  //En lugar de los console.log tú quieres hacer un alert con la información que te interese. En tu caso deberías comprobar si es un pikachu (desconozco el código del pikachu, queda para que lo pienses tú)
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      console.log("Se ha añadido un elemento " + mutation.addedNodes[0].tagName);
    } else if (mutation.removedNodes.length > 0) {
      console.log("Se ha eliminado un elemento " + mutation.removedNodes[0].tagName);
    }
  });
});

//Esta es la variable de configuración del MutationObserver. En este caso sólo me interesa cuando se añaden/Eliminan elementos.
var config = {
  childList: true
};
//Ejecuto el MutationObserver con la configuración establecida en la variable.
observer.observe(contenido, config);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="controles">
    <button type="button" id="botonAnadir">Añadir</button>
  </div>
  <div id="contenido"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo. Solo que hay un problema no se como introducir en el if la imagen de void, por que si no alertara en cada movimiento.Entiendo el mecanismo pero no se como implementarlo corectamente te dejo el espacio web para comprobar como funciona el juego.
http://www.pokemonbattlearena.net/members/